# How to get the date in separate textbox in veu js?

Tags: javascript, php

mounted(){

```
        $(this.$refs.confirm_dt_modal).on("hidden.bs.modal", this.modalHide);

        var self = this;

        $('#confirmdt_start_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onSelect:function(selectedDate, datePicker) {
                self.start_date = selectedDate;
                       }
    });
```

im trying to show the date in separate textbox

Comment: Please add more details to your question please

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:
make a function > that assign a value of new textbox like below

```js
<input type="text" id="newtextboxID" /> <!--Make textbox in html-->
</body>
<script> // add script @ appropriate position
function new(){
document.GetElementById("#newtextboxID").value = OldVariable;
}</script>
<script>
$(this.$refs.confirm_dt_modal).on("hidden.bs.modal", this.modalHide);

        var self = this;

        $('#confirmdt_start_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onSelect:function(selectedDate, datePicker) {
               self.start_date = selectedDate;
//check below line 
OldVariable = self.start_date;
new();  /// ---> this function call will fill up value of newtextbox

                       }
    });

</script>
```